# How can an access token be shared between server names? (www vs non www)

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

I am currently developing an app via website and the token that Facebook returns back will only be in session for the exact url. In other words, if a user hits site.com and logs in, the token only works for site.com. If the user tries to manually type in www.site.com, the token does not apply.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access_token is not tied to a domain.  You can even use a valid user token here:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer  Give it a try.  You can even use it to do things in the graph via a desktop application too.

The app you're using might be setting a session cookie, and that might be tied to a domain though, and that may be the source of your issues.